# WPF DataTrigger not firing when Application style applied?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styling, datatrigger

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated as I have been looking around all day for answers surrounding this area!

I have applied a global style to my WPF application by adding in a merged dictionary to the App.xaml.  This has applied the style across the application like intended but there are a number of things that it has done that I do not fully understand.

I can give you the code that the style is applying if that will help but it is quite large so though it best not to clog this post.  The style applies a background colour to each of the listbox items as well as cool hover over animations and colour changes.  This style was not applied to a couple of the listboxes in my application though, code example of one below:

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,15,0,0" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <converter:IntToBoolConverter x:Key="intToBoolConverter" />
        <converter:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Label Content="Required Vehicles" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <ListBox x:Name="lstVehicleRequests" ItemsSource="{Binding VehicleRequests}" Width="auto"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseListBoxItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=RequestStatus.RequestStatusId}" Value="7">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFB" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="IndianRed" Offset="0.5" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFB" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="4" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,8,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,4,10,0" >
                        <Label Content="Coach Type" Width="120" />
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.CoachTypes, 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding CoachType}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Width="100" />
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,8,10,0">
                            <Label Content="No of Passengers" Width="120" />
                            <TextBox 
                                    keys:ValidKeys.Numeric="True"
                                    Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
                                    Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}" Width="50">
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                        <Binding Path="Passengers"
                                                  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                                <val:RegularExpressionRule 
                                                    ErrorDescription="Please Enter a Numeric Size" 
                                                    RegularExpression="^\d*$" />
                                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        </Binding>
                                    </TextBox.Text>
                            </TextBox>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,8,10,0">
                            <Label Content="No of Drivers" Width="120" />
                            <TextBox
                                    keys:ValidKeys.Numeric="True"
                                    Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
                                    Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}" Width="50">
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="Drivers"
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                            <val:RegularExpressionRule 
                                                ErrorDescription="Please Enter a Numeric Size" 
                                                RegularExpression="^\d*$" />
                                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        </Binding>
                                    </TextBox.Text>
                            </TextBox>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,8,10,0">
                        <Label Content="Positioning Feeder Drivers" Width="120" />
                            <TextBox
                                    keys:ValidKeys.Numeric="True"
                                    Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}" Width="50" MaxLength="3">
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="PositioningFeederDrivers"
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                            <val:RegularExpressionRule 
                                                ErrorDescription="Please Enter a Numeric Size" 
                                                RegularExpression="^\d*$" />
                                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        </Binding>
                                    </TextBox.Text>
                            </TextBox>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,8,10,0">                    
                        <Label Content="Wheelchair Access" Width="120" />
                        <ComboBox Width="100" SelectedIndex="{Binding WheelchairAccess, 
                                  Converter={StaticResource intToBoolConverter}}">
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Not Required" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Required" />
                        </ComboBox>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,8,10,8">
                        <Label Content="Trailer" Width="120" />
                        <ComboBox Width="100" SelectedIndex="{Binding Trailer, 
                                  Converter={StaticResource intToBoolConverter}}">
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Not Required" />
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Required" />
                        </ComboBox>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I then added the BasedOn property as you can see above, why did I have to do this to get the style applied to this list box? Other listboxes and different controls picked this up automatically?

Anyway, you will see that I have a datatrigger against this listbox which should change the backround colour when the request status id = 7.  Without the based on property the row successfully changes colour to red.  When the style is applied it never changes colour and the orange colour from the template is always applied.

HELP?????

Much appreciated,

Mark

Comment: If the color changes to red without the BasedOn property, then your style is being applied to your ListBox properly, otherwise it wouldn't have changed.  Where is the orange color in the template?  What are the different types of controls you're using that exhibit different behavior with this Style definition?

Comment: The orange colour is applied to this list box from the baseListBox style which is imported from the App.Xaml as a merged dictionary. We use most of the controls throughout our app, listboxes, combo boxes, labels, textboxes etc etc...  All of these picked up the style from App.xaml without the need to add the BasedOn property. I thought it may be something to do with the fact we are changing the data template of the listbox?

The main question is that with the BasedOn property being included, why will the background not change with the datatrigger?
I have included the base stlye below

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style x:Key="BaseListBoxItem" d:IsControlPart="True" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource OutsideFontColor}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOn">
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientOver" 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.73" />
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOff">
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientOver" 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="SelectedOn">
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientSelected" 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.84" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientSelectedDisabled" 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.55" />
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="SelectedOff">
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientSelected" 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientSelectedDisabled" 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradientOver" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource MouseOverBorderBrush}" 
                                   Opacity="0" Fill="{DynamicResource MouseOverBrush}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradientSelectedDisabled" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0" Fill="{DynamicResource 
                            ListItemSelectedBrush}" Stroke="{DynamicResource ListItemSelectedBorderBrush}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradientSelected" Stroke="{DynamicResource PressedBorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" 
                                   RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0" Fill="{DynamicResource PressedBrush}">

                        </Rectangle>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"  />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SelectedOff}" x:Name="SelectedOff_BeginStoryboard" />
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SelectedOn}" x:Name="SelectedOn_BeginStoryboard" />
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>

                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOff}" x:Name="HoverOff_BeginStoryboard" />
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOn}" />
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```